# Spring Security OAuth2 & Zuul Proxy

Tags: spring, oauth, proxy, netflix-zuul

I have a simple environment:

- A Proxy Zuul Server
- A Authorization Server
- A UI Service
- A Resource Server

My problem comes when I want to get the token. I would like that only the proxy server becomes public to the outside world, while the other services remain in the private network.

When I go on the proxy, it forwards me to the authentication server in order to authenticate. The problem is that the forwarding starts using the authentication server port instead of maintaining the original proxy port.

Looks like this:

1. Request URL:http://localhost:8080/ Request Method:GET, Location:http://localhost:8080/login
2. Request URL:http://localhost:8080/login Request Method:GET, Location:http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize?client_id=ui1&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&response_type=code&state=u8OhCF
3. Request URL:http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize?client_id=ui1&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&response_type=code&state=u8OhCF Request Method:GET, Location:http://localhost:9999/uaa/login
4. Request URL:http://localhost:9999/uaa/login Request Method:GET

Can I make the Zuul Proxy be a complete proxy and auto-transform the :9999 port back to :8080 ?
Also, since the authentication server also does step 3 redirect, will zuul know to translate this ?

The current zuul config is:

```
zuul:  
  routes:    
    startpage:
      path: /**
      url: http://localhost:8081
    resource:      
      path: /resource/**
      url: http://localhost:9001/resource
    user:
      path: /user/**
      url: http://localhost:9999/uaa/user
```